# How many humans would I need to skin to create a bulletproof full body suit

Tags: biology, humans, armors

How many humans would I need to skin to create a bulletproof full body suit. The main thing is that I am a guy who wants to not get shot and I happen to enjoy harvesting human flesh and I am dead set on achieving my goal. How many humans am I going to need to obtain in order to create my suit? There is some wiggle room in how the suit can be constructed but I want to stick to the following guidelines.

- Its main material is human flesh.
- I also am going to need enough flesh to create a suit that encompasses my whole body.
- By bullet proof you can assume I am trying to achieve the same result as a normal kevlar vest. I want to stop the bullet from reaching my skin. I may have some major bruises and it might hurt but I should come away reasonably unharmed.
- The skin can be modified or treated but I want it to mainly be skin after its modifications. A process like what we do to leather would not be out of the question, since its not drastically changing what the material is made of.
- I get that the amount of skin that I may need to be wearing could be much heavier and bulkier than anything a normal human may be able to carry. That's something I am willing to figure out, but bonus points if you think of a great method of augmenting the suit to get around that issue.

Comment: Even a fat man who weighs a 1000lbs can not stop a bullet.

Comment: Eww! Do you want fresh skin, boiled skin, treated with polymers etc?

Comment: depends on the gun.  Your never stopping one of these, https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-65da27a44a50b3377d6b16950d306b53-c

Comment: So many that you would overheat and become immobile after putting on the suit.

Comment: So this question is quite disturbing, and I admit to having a great deal of trouble seeing how it could actually be used in a worldbuilding effort (probably out of a subconscious choice not to visualize such worlds).  However, a big question would be "what is bullet proof?"  Bullet proof vests are graded to work against some bullets and not others.  I can 100% guarantee you that no bullet proof armor can protect you against a 16" round fired from an Iowa class battleship.

Answer (score 8):

Myth busters once tested the aforementioned obese myth by creating a 10 foot tube and filling it appropriately with enough material to simulate an inhumanly obese human gut and placed it in front of there standard ballistic gel dummy and fired a shot at distance.  The bullet traveled the length of the tube and still had enough energy to exit the gel dummy, which would be a lethal wound.  A human shield only works if the shooter does not wish to kill the human in front of the target. It is psychological, not practical.

Comment: Do you have a link to the test? Most rifle rounds don't penetrate all that far into ballistic gel, so I'm curious as to what they filled the tube with such that a round could penetrate ten feet.

Comment: I'll have to go find it.  Obviously, that means I might have mis-remembered it as a through and through shot, but it was definitely fatal and cleared the tube.

Comment: Hitting bone slows down the bullet quite a bit though.  While that's not relevant to the question above, it is relevant to the human shield you mention.  If it hits the ribs or bone of the person/body you're hiding behind, you have a good chance of surviving.

Answer (score 4):

Ballistic gel is meant to simulate the properties of human flesh. Thus, ballistic gel testing can provide an approximation of how much human body you need between you and a bullet to stop it.

[This article](http://www.activeresponsetraining.net/ar-15-rifle-ballistic-gel-testing-results-best-choices-for-a-defensive-rifle-round) tested a number of different loads of .223/5.56mm caliber, which is a common intermediate cartridge. The typical penetration, going through 'heavy clothing', appears to be around 24".

This means that, in order to stop a .223 short, you'll need at least 24" of flesh in between you and the bullet. This won't even stop a full-sized rifle caliber, such as used by hunting or sniper's rifles, but it will protect against most pistol, shotgun, and submachine gun rounds.

Two feet of depth is a lot of flesh, well past the point of being a 'suit'. On that basis, I'd say that this question is not really answerable- it's far past body armor and firmly into 'flesh golem' territory.